# How much of the "Princess Jellyfish" manga was adapted into the anime?

Tags: princess-jellyfish

The **"Princess Jellyfish" (*Kuragehime*)** anime aired in 2010, but the manga kept on being published until 2017. Presumably only the chapters published between 2008 and 2010 were adapted, but it's common for adaptations of ongoing manga to differ from the source material.

How much of the manga was adapted into the anime?
And how much does the storyline differ from the source material?